# How to upload image save in Storage and then get Url in DB

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, storage

I am uploading the image into Storage in Firebase and DB, but I have an issue that

```
TypeError: _config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.firestore is not a function
```

This is my code in API for my data, it has just DB not have storage yet, how can I put both images into storage and get downloadUrl in DB.

```
const firebaseDb = firebaseApp.database();
const fireStore = firebaseApp.firestore();

/**
 * Representation for creating new product and save to database
 */
export const doCreateProduct = (productData, image_url) => {
  const productId = firebaseDb.ref().push().key;
  return firebaseDb
    .ref(`products/${productId}`)
    .set(productData)
    .then(() => {
      return onceGetProducts();
    })
    .catch((error) => ({
      error,
      status: "failure",
    }));
};
```

And this is my handleImageFile in form

```
const [imageFile, setImageFile] = useState();

console.log(imageFile);
  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    console.log("file image", event);
    const image = event.target.files[0]
    setImageFile(imageFile => (image))
  };

  //onSave is a button save after input 
  const onSave = () => {
    createProductRequest(values, imageFile);
  };
```

Anybody here can help me with this problem, please? Thank you so much

Comment: How are you importing firebase? My guess is you're doing `import firebase from 'firebase'` instead of `import * as firebase from 'firebase'`.

Comment: I import like this ```import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/storage";